# Loss of image quality when zooming in Flex Mobile application

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder, zooming

i have a mobile application that i am creating in Adobe Flex (Flash Builder 4), and i am trying to create a zoom function. The one i have works, but the point is to be able to more easily read words that are in the image (the images are .jpg files). The images are 2550x3300 originally, but as soon as you zoom, the image quality reduces drastically, and nothing is readable.

My code for the zoom function is included below.

```
        protected function onZoom(e:TransformGestureEvent, img:Image):void
        {
            img.transformAround(new Vector3D(e.localX, e.localY, 0), new Vector3D(img.scaleX*e.scaleX, img.scaleY*e.scaleY, 0));
        }
```

and this is the code for the image object:

```
<s:Image id="titlepage" includeIn="title_page" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="415" 
         gesturePan="onPan(event, titlepage)" 
         gestureSwipe="onSwipe(event)" 
         gestureZoom="onZoom(event, titlepage)" 
         source="@Embed('assets/myImage.jpg')"/>
```

Comment: Show more code around the Image object.  Also, why are you doing a transform and not just scaling the image?

Comment: added the code for the image object. and before, scaling was simply increasing and decreasing the size, the transformAround() method allowed you to anchor the action to the point you were zooming on. Can you do this another way?

Comment: using `img.scaleX *= e.scaleX; img.scaleY *= e.scaleY;` zooms on the picture without much quality loss, but still zooms to the top left corner. is there a way to make it anchor to where your fingers are actually zooming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image quality would be improved by setting smooth to true for anti-aliasing.

```
<s:Image smooth="true" />
```

There are many ways to handle registration issues - you might be interested in Yahoo Astra utils [DynamicRegistration class](http://code.google.com/p/flexwires/source/browse/trunk/examples/IntroductionToJacks/com/yahoo/astra/utils/DynamicRegistration.as?r=5).

Maybe something like this?

```
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.yahoo.astra.utils.DynamicRegistration;

            protected function image_gestureZoomHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
            {
                DynamicRegistration.scale(image,
                                          new Point(event.localX, event.localY),
                                          image.scaleX *= event.scaleX,
                                          image.scaleY *= event.scaleY);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Image id="image"
             smooth="true"
             gestureZoom="image_gestureZoomHandler(event)" />
```

Comment: Are you getting errors, or can you describe the functional problem?

Comment: @JacobL, what about using that class as he mentioned.  It's perfect since it scales the image as well as keep the registration point of the touch event, just like you want it.

Comment: @Jason Sturges, nice find on that class, I will definitely use it instead of just doing my own algo :)

Comment: i tried this, copy and pasting the code, and it still does the same thing as just scaling. The zoom function still anchors to the top left corner (0,0).

Comment: @Jason @J_A_X, i find this odd, because when i used the same function for a "double click to zoom", it did the correct thing, zooming to the registered point. The only difference in the function call was that i used 2 for the zoom factor instead of the dynamic scale ones.

Comment: @JacobL, Can you post more code about the context of the Image class? Is it wrapped in something?

Comment: nope, it's just on the stage.

`<s:View> ... <s:Image.../> </s:View>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive on this, but I think the 'transform' functions creates a bitmap out of your Image which is why you're losing quality.  Try using the 'smoothing' attribute on your image.

From there, it's simply scaling and moving your image incrementally.  However, what I'm not sure about is if the localX/Y property is from the original place of touch, or of the new position on the container (ie. if you're pinch/zooming from the middle and it scales, will the point still be on the middle or slightly top left).

I'll try to test this out on my phone and see what I come up with.